# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT - Json Web Tokens en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, tokens, webtoken

Estoy intentando en implementar el JSON TOKEN en node.js pero tengo este error:

> [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:469:11)

Este es el código que tengo:

```
router.post('/api/v1/Login', jsonParser, function(req, res){
  if(!req.body)
  return res.sendStatus(400)
  console.log(req.body);

  var UsuarioReg = req.body.user;
  var ContraReg = req.body.pass;

  console.log("User: "+UsuarioReg + " Contraseña: "+ContraReg)


  var request = new sql.Request();

  try{

      request.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.[Client] WHERE username = '"+UsuarioReg+"'AND pass = '"+ContraReg+"'", function (err, recordset) {
        if(err){
        console.log(err); 
        }else{
          if(recordset.rowsAffected > 0){
            res.write(JSON.stringify("Usuario identificado correctamente"))

            console.log("Usuario identificado correctamente")

            const user = {id: 3};
            const token = jwt.sign({ user },'my_secret_key');

            res.json({
              token:token
            });
          }
        }
      })
    }catch(err){
      res.send(JSON.stringify("Error while querying database :- "+err))
      console.log("Error while querying database :- "+err)
    }

});
```

No entiendo a que se debe este error. Me ayudan? Gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

segun indicas, el error que te muestra es porque no se puede modificar la cabecera despues de enviar los datos.

Este error lo he solucionado realizando los siguiente:

1.- Middleware en Express

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

// Dominio que tengan acceso (ej. 'http://example.com')
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Metodos de solicitud que deseas permitir
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

// Encabecedados que permites (ej. 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

next();
})
```

2.- Cors (modulo de npm)

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Por defecto, utiliza la misma cabecera que la petición entrante.
Podrías cambias la configuración por defecto, para ello te recomiendo que revises esta documentación:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Espero haberte ayudado

Saludos