# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, fileupload, rutas

este es mi codigo de Node.

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Usuario = require('../models/usuario');


// default options
app.use(fileUpload());

app.put('/upload/:tipo/:id', function (req, res) {
    let tipo = req.params.tipo;
    let id = req.params.id;

    if (Object.keys(req.files).length == 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'No se ha seleccionado ningun archivo'
            }
        });
    }

    //Valida tipo 
    const tiposValidos = ['productos','usuarios'];
    if(tiposValidos.indexOf(tipo)<0){
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'Los tipos validos son ' + tiposValidos.join(' y '),
                tipo : tipo
            }
        });
    }
    // The name of the input field (i.e. "archivo") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
    let archivo = req.files.archivo;
    let nombreCortado = archivo.name.split('.');
    let extension = nombreCortado[nombreCortado.length-1];
    // Extensiones permitidas 
    const extensionesValida = ['png','jpg','gif','jpeg'];
    if(extensionesValida.indexOf(extension) < 0){
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'La extensiones permitidas son ' + extensionesValida.join(', '),
                ext : extension
            }
        });
    }


    //Cambiar nombre Archivo
    let nombreArchivo = `${id}-${new Date().getMilliseconds()}.${extension}`;

    archivo.mv(`uploads/${ tipo }/${nombreArchivo}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            });
        }

        imagenUsuario(id,res,nombreArchivo);
        //Imagen Cargada

        res.json({
            ok: true,
            message: 'Archivo enviado'
        })
    });
});

function imagenUsuario(id,res,nombreArchivo){
    Usuario.findById(id,(err,usuarioDB)=>{
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            });
        }
        if(!usuarioDB){
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                err: {message: 'No existe el usuario'
            }});
        }
        let pathImage = path.resolve(__dirname,`../../uploads/usuarios/${usuarioDB.img}`);
        if(fs.existsSync(pathImage)){
            fs.unlinkSync(pathImage);
        }
        usuarioDB.img = nombreArchivo;
        usuarioDB.save((err,usuarioGuardado)=>{
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }
            res.json({
                ok: true,
                usuario: usuarioGuardado
            })
        })
    })
}


function imagenProducto(){

}

module.exports = app;
```

Como se puede ver es un codigo de express para subir imagenes. El problema radica en que cuando intento validar que un usuario no puede subir la misma imagen o al menos intento aparece esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que significa y al ser nuevo no entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento de node, asi que agradeceria que me ayudaran de forma simple. De antemano gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre el error que te aparece es porque estas respondiendo sin indicar una cabecera en tu respuesta, te envío un enlace relacionado con el error al que respondí hace un tiempo:

[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT - Json Web Tokens en Node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197381/err-http-headers-sent-json-web-tokens-en-node-js/199585#199585)

Por otro lado, viendo tu código hay una cosa que no veo claro del todo, en la función `imagenUsuario` envías el objeto `res` para responder desde esa función pero a continuación también la usas, pienso que seria mejor que utilizaras la función para gestionar la imagen del Usuario y que este te respondiera si se realizo correctamente o no, de esta forma separa responsabilidades en tu código. Te pongo un ejemplo para que puedas entenderlo:

```
archivo.mv(`uploads/${tipo}/${nombreArchivo}`, (err) => {
if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ ok: false, err });
}

// No enviamos el objeto Response
imagenUsuario(id, nombreArchivo, (user) => {
    if (user.ok) {
    const { status, ok, message } = user //Destructuring ES6
    res.status.(status).json({ ok: ok, message: message }) //Tambien ...json({ok, message}) ES6
    } else {
    const { status, ok, err } = user //Destructuring ES6
    res.status.(status).json({ ok: ok, err: err }) //Tambien ...json({ok, err}) ES6
    }
});
});
```

```
function imagenUsuario(id, nombreArchivo, callback){
    Usuario.findById(id, (err, usuarioDB) =>{
        if (err)
            callback({status:500, ok:false, err:err.message})

        if(!usuarioDB)
            callback({status:400, ok:false, err:'No existe el usuario'})

        let pathImage = path.resolve(__dirname,`../../uploads/usuarios/${usuarioDB}`);
        if(fs.existsSync(pathImage)){
            fs.unlinkSync(pathImage);
        }
        usuarioDB.img = nombreArchivo;
        usuarioDB.save((err, usuarioGuardado) => {
            if (err)
                 callback({status:500, ok:false, err:err.message})

            callback({status:200, ok:true, message: 'Archivo guardado'})
        })
    })
}
```

Para la función `imagenUsuario` he utilizado 'callback' para obtener la respuesta asíncrona pero podrías realizarlo con `Promise` o `Async/Await`.

- [Info Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)
- [Info Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

*Confirmanos si pudiste solucionar el error con esta explicación que te facilite y si no es así avísanos para poder ayudarte.*

Comment: Sí, me ha servido, ya reemplaza la imagen del usuario sin producir copia o algún tipo de error. Gracias !!!

Comment: Genial @Alezco05!!! Me alegro!!! Gracias por avisar!!!
Si la respuesta te resolvió el problema, deberías considerar el aceptarla (símbolo del check, a la izquierda). (¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta? -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)