# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client (JWT)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express, jwt

Estoy haciendo una api con node.js, encontre este error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error comenzó al empezar a usar las variables userId2 e id_user para verificar que la transacción pertenece al usuario

este es mi código:

```js
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        conn.query(`use ${config.database}`);
        
        const {id_user} = req; //recover id_user

        const {amount, concept, type, category, date} = req.body;
        const newBody = {amount, concept, type, category, date, id_user};
        conn.query(`SELECT id_user FROM transaction WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`, (err, rows) =>{
            if (err) return res.status(500).json({error: err.message})
            const {id_user: userId2} = rows[0];
            console.log(userId2); 
            console.log(id_user);
            if(userId2 !== id_user){
                return res.status(403).json({error: 'permission to access resource denied, invalid token'});
            }
        })
        
        //add transaction
        conn.query('UPDATE transaction set ? WHERE id = ?',[newBody, req.params.id] ,(err, rows) => {
            const {error} = validateAmount(req.body.amount);//validate amount format
            if(error){
                return res.json({error: "enter a valid amount"})
            }
            if(err) return res.json({error: err.message})

            res.json({data: 'the transaction has been updated'});
            
        });
```

**User extractor**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, disculpa no me había dado cuenta, ya la edite

Comment: Te dejo un enlace para que verifiques si te ayuda con tu problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197381/err-http-headers-sent-json-web-tokens-en-node-js

Comment: Revise esa pregunta y no me funciono, gracias igualmente.